# What does sequence attribute in menuitem tags?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

With the following XML code:

```
<menuitem
  id="library_book_menu"
  name="Library"
  action="library_book_action"
  parent=""
  sequence="5" />
```

What does `sequence` attribute is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets the place of the menus and the submenus.

For example one menuitem with sequence 4 will be on the left of a menuitem with sequence 12 at the topbar.

At the leftbar, the one with sequence 4 will be above the one with sequence 12.